# In "Utopia", how does Martha know the Master's voice?

Tags: doctor-who

In "Utopia" of the new Season 3, as the Master has regenerated, Martha states that she recognises the voice from inside the TARDIS.  How does she know the voice?

Comment: Piece of advice: I'd be careful with asking DW questions to episodes you're watching, as the answers can easily spoil a lot of subsequent episodes for you. Especially in the seasons that lie before you.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually watched all the new ones and was re-watching season 3, and that bit confused me.  Thanks though :)

Comment: Since the Master posed as Saxon during the present day, maybe it was like one of those "changing the future" things, where things have just "happened."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because

> The Master, after regenerating, goes back to the past, 18 months before the 2008 elections, and assumes the identity of **Harold Saxon**, who will be candidate to become Prime Minister. Therefore, **The Master** was already in the UK before the fall of [Harriet Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harriet_Jones), meaning that Martha could have heard him while in campaign, in the news, or so.

Comment: Heh, I then watched the next two episodes and was (facepalm) that answered that one.  Cheers for the quick response.